# remove mat-form-field outline-gap

Tags: css, angular-material

Notice the outline gap? I want that closed. I don't want a gap to be there, I want a continues borderline.

[image]

I've tried this

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-gap:active {
  border-style: solid !important;
}
```

Comment: which gap you are talking about? please take a screenshot and round your gap and upload in imgur, so it will be visible to all

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
  border-top-color: initial !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

avoid using ::ng-deep (deprecated) and avoid using !important -- these are not good practices anymore.

you can directly add class in Global css like that:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline
.mat-form-field-can-float
.mat-form-field-should-float
.mat-form-field-outline-gap {
  border-top-color: initial !important;
}
```

I hope,I could help.

Comment: Nope, I don't wanna use `ViewEncapsulation`. That can snowball into a lot more issues than just trying to fix a borderline. I don't have the energy to deal with the cascade of uncertainties ViewEncapsulation comes with, especially in the kinda project I was working with

Comment: I have Updated my Answer it also works like that if you  don't want to use ViewEncapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why, the answers didnt work for me.

So I did this on my global styles.scss:

```css
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float
  .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
  border-top-color: initial !important;
}

.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float
  .mat-form-field-label,
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float
  .mat-input-server:focus
  + .mat-form-field-label-wrapper
  .mat-form-field-label {
  transform: translateY(-0.8em) scale(0.75);
}
```